# Unable to connect hive2 via JDBC java program

Tags: java, hadoop, jdbc, hive, hiveql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6x3p.png)

As I have import all required JAR file as shown in above image.
But still it gives me error while trying to connect hive2 via java program.

Error gives me on this line.

**Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default", "", "");**

**Error:**

```
18/05/30 17:12:15 INFO jdbc.Utils: Supplied authorities: localhost:10000
18/05/30 17:12:15 INFO jdbc.Utils: Resolved authority: localhost:10000
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hive.common.auth.HiveAuthUtils.getSocketTransport(Ljava/lang/String;II)Lorg/apache/thrift/transport/TTransport;
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.createUnderlyingTransport(HiveConnection.java:519)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.createBinaryTransport(HiveConnection.java:539)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openTransport(HiveConnection.java:309)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:196)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:107)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at Hive_java.main(Hive_java.java:15)
```

**JAVA Code:**

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
public class Hive_java{
  private static String driver = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";  //driver used for hiveserver2
  public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    try {
      Class.forName(driver);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.exit(1);
    }
    Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default", "", "");   //connecting to default database
    Statement state = connect.createStatement();
    System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!Running 1st query!!!!!!!!!!");
    System.out.println("Listing tables in hive");
    ResultSet show_tables = state.executeQuery("show tables");
    while (show_tables.next()) {
        System.out.println(show_tables.getString(1));
    }
    System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!Running 2nd query!!!!!!!!!!");
    System.out.println("Describing slave3_tbl table");
    ResultSet describe_table = state.executeQuery("describe slave3_tbl");
    while (describe_table.next()) {
        System.out.println(describe_table.getString(1) + "\t" + describe_table.getString(2));
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the code ?

Comment: @Gaurav Varshney I updated question as per your requirement. Please check.

Comment: outdated "hive common" maybe

Comment: @mangusta I have used same version of hive-common jar file as of hive version i.e 2.3.2.